# SQL SERVER - "Invalid column name '0'

Tags: python, sql-server

This is the query I am sending:

```
 SELECT "*" FROM "tkscale" WHERE "UfText1" IN ("12","23","45","0");
```

But I am getting the following error.

> Error (pymssql._pymssql.ProgrammingError) (207, b"Invalid column name
> '0'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server
> error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018,
> severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL
> Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server
> error: Check messages from the SQL Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018,
> severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL
> Server\nDB-Lib error message 20018, severity 16:\nGeneral SQL Server
> error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

I create the query like this:

```
table="tkscale",
cols="*",
where="UfText1",
ids=[12, 23, 45, 0]

SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT {cols} FROM {table} WHERE {where} IN ({ids});"
query = SELECT_QUERY.format(
        table='"{}"'.format(table),
        where='"{}"'.format(where),
        ids=",".join(['"{}"'.format(id) for id in ids]), 
        cols=",".join(['"{}"'.format(col) for col in cols]), 
    )
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to format a string inside a formatted string. So `table='"{}"'.format(table)` is point less and you can just do `table=table`. Secondly the issue is with the `cols` variable yet you show us no code that shows what is assigned to the variable.

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide Check my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of those things should be "wrapped" "in" "double" "quotes." Perhaps try something like this:

```python
query = SELECT_QUERY.format(
        table='{}'.format(table),
        where='{}'.format(where),
        ids=",".join(['{}'.format(id) for id in ids]), 
        cols=",".join(['{}'.format(col) for col in cols]), 
    )
```

Or simpler as, uh, TeddyBearSuicide suggested:

```python
query = SELECT_QUERY.format(
        table=table,
        where=where,
        ids=",".join(['{}'.format(id) for id in ids]), 
        cols=",".join(['{}'.format(col) for col in cols]), 
    )
```

Comment: So simple and I did not see it. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Legna you bet. If you are worried that you might have table or column names that need to be escaped, the better practice in SQL Server (at least IMHO) is to use `[square brackets]` instead of `"double quotes"` (not because one is better than the other, they both work, but mostly because square brackets can't later be confused with string literals).

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're talking about? The use is not very clear to me.

Comment: @Legna if you had a poorly chosen table or column name like `123` or `who blats`, in SQL Server, you'd need to reference it as either `[123]`/`[who blats]` or `"123"`/`"who blats"`. The former is far more readable.